# Simple MPI_Sendrecv program give a signal 11 (segfault)

Tags: parallel-processing, mpi

I am very new to MPI. I am trying to run the following program using `MPI_Sendrecv` on `p` processes. Each process has 4 arrays (A, B, C, D) of length `n` with any values of type double. Now this is what I want to do `for i=0,...,p-1`:

process i sends B to A in process (i+1)%p

process i sends C to D in process (i-1)%p

process i receives B from (i-1)%p into A

process i receives C from (i+1)%p into D

I have the following code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<mpi.h>
#include<math.h>

main(int argc, char *argv[]){

/*Initialize the MPI environment          */
/******************************************/
MPI_Init(&argc, &argv);

/*variables that will be used for sending*/
/*and receiving messages.                */
/*****************************************/
int n=3;
int p;
int myRank;
int comm;

double A[n];
double C[n];
double B[n];
double D[n];

/*Get the number of processors and their  */
/*rank.                                   */
/******************************************/
comm = MPI_COMM_WORLD;
MPI_Comm_size(comm, &p);
MPI_Comm_rank(comm, &myRank);

/*Initialize the arrays with the given    */
/*initial values.                         */
/******************************************/
for(int i=0; i<n; i++){
  A[i]=0;       D[i]=0;
  B[i]=-myRank; C[i]=myRank;
}

int left = myRank-1; int right = myRank+1;

if(left<0){
  left = p-1;
}

if(right==p){
  right = 0;
}

MPI_Sendrecv(&B,n,MPI_DOUBLE,right,1231,
             &A,n,MPI_DOUBLE,left,1231,
             comm,MPI_STATUS_IGNORE);
MPI_Sendrecv(&C,n,MPI_DOUBLE,left,1232,
             &D,n,MPI_DOUBLE,right,1232,
             comm,MPI_STATUS_IGNORE);


/*Close the MPI environment.              */
/******************************************/
MPI_Finalize();

/*Print the updated values.               */
for(int i=0; i<p; i++){
  printf("\n");
  for(int j=0; j<n; j++){
    if(myRank==i){
      printf("rank= %d, Updated Values = A[%d]= %f, B[%d]= %f, 
              C[%d]= %f, D[%d]= %f\n", myRank,j,A[j],j,B[j],j,C[j],j,D[j]);                   
    }
  }
 }

 }
```

However, whenever I run this code I get the following:

```
vincent% mpicc -o hmw2Prob1 hmw2Prob1.c
vincent% mpirun -np 4 hmw2Prob1
2: signal 11 received, exiting..
2: Signal sent from unknown source.
3: signal 11 received, exiting..
3: Signal sent from unknown source.
0: signal 11 received, exiting..
0: Signal sent from unknown source.
1: signal 11 received, exiting..
1: Signal sent from unknown source.
vincent%
```

I have read several post here and tried some of the ideas there but nothing has worked so far. I will appreciate any help you can provide.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the adress-of (&) and rather use like `MPI_Sendrecv(B ...` in all cases. `B` is the address of the array/buffer, `&B` the address of the variable holding the address of the array/buffer. When working with MPI (and C in general) it is essential to have a good Understanding of pointers - unfortunately I do not have good material explaining this, but I am sure you will find plenty.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Unfortunately, I did try that as I saw in some other posts that for some people having similar problems it did fixed it. But the problem was that they started pointing to a pointer. In my case I am declaring all the arrays in the beginning and not just the addresses. I have been stuck on this for a couple of days and I am out of ideas other than do it with normal sends and recv's but the whole point was to do it with the MPI Sendrecv command.

Comment: Please post your updated program and the precise errors you get with that, your implementation and system configuration. The program works for me if you remove the incorrect `&`. Also i **strongly** encourage you to lean more about pointers, arrays and memory locations in C. You should **never** be just guessing or trying whether `x` `&x` `*x` appears to work.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to the people that took the time to read my question. At the end what was wrong with my  code  was that in the Sendrecv:

```
MPI_Sendrecv(&B,n,MPI_DOUBLE,right,1231,
         &A,n,MPI_DOUBLE,left,1231,
         comm,MPI_STATUS_IGNORE);
MPI_Sendrecv(&C,n,MPI_DOUBLE,left,1232,
         &D,n,MPI_DOUBLE,right,1232,
         comm,MPI_STATUS_IGNORE);
```

You **can't** use MPI_STATUS_IGNORE, I still haven't figured out all the inner workings of MPI but from what I have read the system needs the MPI_Status *status in order to resolve the message passing order.

In any case if anyone has suggestion for further learning MPI please let me know.